# MySQL relationship query

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join

I have two tables, the 1st:

```
users(id,name, birth_date)
skills(user_id,skill_name,skill_level)
```

I want to select all users with 3 some skills on level 2.

its possible make this in one query ?

example:

```
user has
3,marcus,19/03/1989
4,anderson,08/02/1990

skills has
3,php,2
3,html,1
4,php,1
```

what i want is: all users who has php 2 AND html 1.

Comment: Yes it is possible, but it isn't exactly clear what you would like to see as a result.

Comment: i think this time it's fairly simple to understand the question. Unlike many other 1 rep users

Comment: nevermind it seems he completly changed his question.. doh..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select *
   from users u join skills s on u.id=s.user_id 
   where skill_level=2 
   group by id 
   having count(*)>2
```

Comment: second line should have id, not in:  from users u join skills s on u.id=s.user_id

Answer (score 2):

Okay. Now that you've updated your question a bit more, the answer becomes "yes, it can be done, but you shouldn't necessarily do it like that".

Firstly, just to show that it can be done:

```
SELECT u.* FROM users u 
INNER JOIN skills s1 ON (u.id = s1.user_id AND s1.skill_name = 'php') 
INNER JOIN skills s2 ON (u.id = s2.user_id AND s2.skill_name = 'html') 
WHERE s1.skill_level = 2 AND s2.skill_level = 1 GROUP BY u.id;
```

Would have saved me quite a bit of typing if you'd explained what you wanted in the beginning! :)

Now should you do the above? It's not very pretty, but the principle is that you join to the table twice for both different skills, using aliases (s1 and s2) to hide the fact that it's the same table. Sometimes this is the right approach. The trouble is that I suspect you'll have loads of variations on this where you want to sometimes find people with lots of skills at different levels, sometimes only one, etcetera. You might find writing the code to automatically generate those queries slightly complicated and it wont necessarily scale well.

You *need* to read up on database normalization to better design your tables. And you should also have an id field for the skills table and then you can more easily use sub-queries when you need to.

Comment: Nope. You replied whilst I was writing. The OP clearly is starting out with SQL so I wanted to give a bit more of a full answer. Why?

Comment: I see. It's always good to explain what you want in more detail. In that case you'll need to add more detail to the WHERE clause. I'll edit my answer in a second...

Comment: It's a good idea to add an ID to the skills table, but I disagree that his database design is fundamentally flawed or that joining to the same table more than once is a poor practice. I disagree that the database above is not normalized as well.

Comment: The reason I say it is not normalised is because of the repeated 'html' and 'php' entries. What the user really wants is three tables: a user table, a skills table and then a user_skills table which marries the other two up with a supplementary field containing the level that skill is possessed at. That's going to lead to much better maintainability down the line. I can tell just by looking at his question that he's going to run into trouble if he doesn't go back and read up on this. ;) (No offense, Mbodock).

Comment: I edited my post whilst you were adding your comment to explain a bit more about the self joins and why I think he's possibly starting down the wrong path with this approach. Just from the nature of the data, I think he's going to end up with some very long-winded queries with many self-joins.

Comment: Many joins or many self-joins are not bad with proper indexes.

Comment: *"You might find writing the code to automatically generate those queries slightly complicated"*: I agree.

Comment: _"Many joins or many self-joins are not bad with proper indexes"_ - fair enough. I agree. :)

Comment: @Mbodock If one of these replies answers your question, can you click on it and accept it, please? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve a list of users who have an HTML skill of 1 and a PHP skill of 2:

```
SELECT u.name
FROM users u JOIN skills s1 ON u.id = s1.user_id AND s1.skill = 'php'
JOIN skills s2 ON u.ud = s2.user_id AND s2.skill = 'html'
WHERE s1.skill_level = 2
AND s2.skill_level = 1
```

If you wanted all of the users with both HTML and PHP you could drop the WHERE clause entirely. If you wanted all of the users with a PHP skill of at least 2, you'd just change the clause to

```
s1.skill_level >= 2
```